# Difference between tar -t and tar -v options

Tags: ubuntu, files, tar, compression, archive

I created a archive using command `tar -cvf filename.tar files` , in this the verbose option simply showed me a list of all the files that i have archived.When i used `tar -tf filename.tar` ,it again simply showed me a list of all files that are archived.I expected that verbose option will show some extra details about the files in archive but it didn't. Then i finally used the command `tar -tvf filename.tar` but here the file list was well explained with some extra features and details similar to the `ls -l` command. So i am pretty much confused what is the actual purpose of the `-v` option as it is giving different results in different contexts and how it is different from the `-t` option.

Comment: "I expected that verbose option will show some extra details about the files in archive but it didn't." But you didn't use a verbose option. "i am pretty much confused what is the actual purpose of the -v option as it is giving different results in different contexts" It usually gives more output than the default without it. So if the default output is different for different contexts, of course the verbose output will naturally be different add well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-v` option [increases `tar`’s verbosity](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/verbose-tutorial.html#SEC15). The default verbosity depends on the command.

`-t` lists the file names contained in the archive. One `-v` adds `ls -l`-style file details.

`-c` and `-x` don’t output anything by default. One `-v` makes them behave like `-t`, listing the file names only; two `-v`s adds the file details.

You can add up to three `-v` options:

```
tar -cvvf ...
tar -cvvvf ...
```